# 32 bit OS support in GCP

Tags: windows, google-compute-engine

I am new with GCP and trying to find out if old Win 2003/2008 32 bit virtual machines are supported for migration?

What about 32 bit linux instance?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, 32-bit OS should work.

Please also note there is usually no advantage for using 32-bit OS, as 64-bit one will run most of 32-bit applications just fine.